# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict_keys

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to categorize data based on certain keyword that *exists* in column.

What I've tried:

```
if  city_dict.keys() in a.lower():
        return city_dict[a.lower()]
    elif "cheshire" in a.lower():
...
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict_keys
  File "/home/abyres/testa.py", line 22, in func
    if  city_dict.keys() in a.lower():
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you created the code if the text is in keys, however it should be the other way around.

your current code is

```
if a.lower() in city_dict.keys()
```

however `I love scotland` is not in city_dict.keys() `['scotland', 'scot', 'sctland', 'Cambrgeshire', 'cambridgeshire', 'idgeshire']`

so you should have the code

```
lst = [i for i in city_dict.keys() if i in a.lower()]
if lst:
    print(city_dict[lst[0]])
```

or

```
    print([city_dict[i] for i in lst]) # for multiple mentions
```

Answer (score -1):

What it sounds like is that you want to know if your key exists as a substring in your data. To do so change your statement

> `if  a.lower() in city_dict.keys():`

to

```
if any(k in a.lower() for k in city_dict.keys()):
```

For example

```
>>> city_dict = {"scotland":"country"}
>>> if any(k in 'I love scotland' for k in city_dict.keys()):
...     print("Is a key")
```

Comment: I've tried that before. unfortunately got the error as in edited question post.

Comment: @swm Ok sorry about that, misunderstood. I updated the answer to a working solution. Hopefully it should work for you now.

Comment: error Exception has occurred: KeyError
'scot54'